# Terminal command to build and install the iPhone app in simulator without launching from Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is there any terminal command that can be used to achieve this?

I know `xcodebuild install -configuration` can compile our xcodeproj from terminal without launching from Xcode, however the compilation files are under iOS but not in the iPhone simulator. I'm hoping one of you smart-folks can help me out.

Answer (score 6):

Hey, i found out that you can do it with:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator2.2
```

This makes a simulator build with version 2.2 ( you can use `xcodebuild -showsdks` to list what u have avail ). I'm stuck with a problem of trying to get it to launch on the phone. xcodebuild -install doesn't seem to do anything for me :S
Any assistance?

Comment: Also consult this technote for additional information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following github project (search for iphonesim)

This will allow you to launch the iphone simulator from the command line.

(Sorry, it won't seem to let me post a valid URL in this answer)