# Installing built iOS App in simulator from terminal?

Tags: ios, build, terminal, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

We build an app through the terminal with xcodebuild and also want to install it in the simulator using the terminal. Any advice on this? Seems tricky.

Comment: Apple has a sample command to run a TEST on Simulator: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html Not sure if that helps figure out how to install the vanilla app on the Simulator (not a Terminal expert).

Answer (score 0):

(Any reason you're just not using the default xcode way?)

Heavy mate. I would bet there's an easy way to do it (I'd imagine)

You could make a simple ssh client in Objective-C and run it on the simulator then simply copy the necessary files with said program. Since it's not going through Apple, you'll probably have a pretty easy time with it.

Oh and it went unanswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434286/is-there-a-command-in-terminal-can-build-and-install-the-iphone-app-in-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

The forum thread, http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=547557, seems to have advice which works:

> Look inside your ~/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/User/Applications/ directory
>   and see what happens inside this
>   directory when you install and run
>   apps using XCode, and also when you
>   delete apps using the Simulator.
>
> You can run the Simulator by itself
>   (without starting XCode).
>
> If you start the Simulator, delete an
>   app, quit the Simulator, put back
>   copies of the files that were deleted
>   from the support directory, and
>   restart the Simulator, the app will
>   reappear in the Simulator.